# Как в python получить от значения spinbox соответствующее количество виджетов Entry?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Есть простое задание, которое мне непонятно, и ответа в сети я не нашёл на него. 
Нужно в соответствии со значением `spinbox` отобразить поля вывода, но у меня ничего кроме `spinbox` не появляется при запуске:

```
import tkinter as tk

def update_entries():
    for entry in entries:
        entry.destroy()
    
    num_entries = int(spinbox.get())
    
    for i in range(num_entries):
        entry = tk.Entry(root)
        entry.pack()

root = tk.Tk()

spinbox = tk.Spinbox(root, from_=0, to=10, command=update_entries)
spinbox.pack()

entries = []
    
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import tkinter as tk

def update_entries():
    global entries                                               # <----

    for entry in entries:
        entry.destroy()
        entries = []                                             # <----
   
    num_entries = int(spinbox.get())
    for i in range(num_entries):
        entry = tk.Entry(root)
        entry.pack()
        entries.append(entry)                                    # <----

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('420x420')
entries = []

spinbox = tk.Spinbox(root, from_=0, to=10, command=update_entries)
spinbox.pack()
   
root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```py
import tkinter as tk

def update_entries():
    num_entries = int(spinbox.get())
    
    for entry in entries:
        entry.destroy()
    
    for i in range(num_entries):
        entry = tk.Entry(root)
        entry.pack()
        entries.append(entry)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Пример Spinbox и полей ввода")

spinbox = tk.Spinbox(root, from_=0, to=10, command=update_entries)
spinbox.pack()

entries = []

update_entries()  # Вызываем update_entries() один раз при запуске программы

root.mainloop()
```